# creating a custom drawable shape

Tags: android, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

I want to create the shape rectangle as shown below the Image.
 what am I supposed to do?
with best regards.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `<vector>`

```
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="8dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="50.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#8CCC13"
        android:pathData="M24 24v-24h-24v24a20 36 0 0 1 24 0z" />

</vector>
```

see below Output :

[image]